# Print values by webscraping dictionary list value creation

Tags: python, web-scraping

I would like to know how to properly place certain string terms into a list from a website that have values and have it process those terms into a convenient way by placing into a function and having the values display. I don't have a function built at the bottom part of the code  in the searchText section yet.  I cannot figure how to make it clean that it will save each one and display onto the command window. I placed ' ' as a template of what to put for each value.

Please let me know if I need to clarify anymore. Thank you.

```py
import requests
import getpass

# Test for credentials 
cred = str(input('Please enter: '))
username = input('')
password = getpass()

# URLs
url = ''+ cred
secondUrl = '' 

# Data load
load={'user': username, 'pass': password}

# Grabbing from url source
print('Please wait..')
with requests.Session() as session:
  post = session.post(secondUrl, data=load)
  s = session.get(url)

x = ['', '', '', '']
Dict = {}

a = s.text

search = a.split(x)[1]
result = search.split('>')[2]
result = result.split('<')[0]
Dict[x] = result
print(Dict)
```

Comment: Would be greatly appreciated if anyone knows how.

Answer (score 0):

The following example, which should give you some pointers and ideas, uses Python 3.7 and the BeautifulSoup4 library. It scrapes the following web page: [Sky Sports Premier League](https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-table) (soccer).

[image]

It extracts the team names and their number of points, and stores that data in a dictionary.

The code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-table'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# navigate down to the table and then the table body:
table = soup.find("table", class_='standing-table__table')
body = table.find("tbody")

data = {}

for row in body.find_all("tr"):
    # team name is grabbed from the first <a> value:
    team = row.find("a").get_text() 
    # 10th <td> element contains the points total, as an
    # array of one element - therefore we slice [9::10]
    # and then get the first (and only) array item [0]
    points = row.findAll("td")[9::10][0].get_text()
    data[team] = points
    #print(team)
    #print(points)

print(data)
```

The output looks like this (formatted for legibility):

```
{
    'Liverpool': '82',
    'Manchester City': '57',
    'Leicester City': '53',
    'Chelsea': '48',
    'Manchester United': '45',
    'Wolverhampton Wanderers': '43',
    'Sheffield United': '43',
    'Tottenham Hotspur': '41',
    'Arsenal': '40',
    'Burnley': '39',
    'Crystal Palace': '39',
    'Everton': '37',
    'Newcastle United': '35',
    'Southampton': '34',
    'Brighton and Hove Albion': '29',
    'West Ham United': '27',
    'Watford': '27',
    'Bournemouth': '27',
    'Aston Villa': '25',
    'Norwich City': '21'
}
```

But the point is, once the data is in a Python dictionary (or whatever structure you want), it is straightforward to manipulate.

The main challenge here is to understand the HTML structure of the site you want to scrape, so you can navigate the HTML tags effectively. Using "View page source" in your browser is a good starting point.

Comment: Hi. Yeah I have the split function since it would have been easier I think to lay out the information I need because I don't know the exact row number and things like that so I was doing the list

Comment: I don't want to print everything. Just certain values from my list